# Rails don't add new table row with ajax/jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have weird problem.

I'm using ajax and jquery to dynamically add rows to table but it's not adding anything however in server logs i have

```
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 7.9ms)
```

and content in the response is

```
$('.products-table tr:last').after('<tr>
  <td>Test</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1.2</td>
  <td>1.2</td>
</tr>');
```

i have tried

```
$('.products-table').append('<tr>
  <td>Test</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1.2</td>
  <td>1.2</td>
</tr>');
```

but it's not working too.

I'm trying to get it into this table

```
<div class="order-bar">
  <div class="order-bar-title">
    Order for table <%= @order.table %>
  </div>
    <div class="order-products-list">
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed products-table">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Price</td> 
        <td>Total</td>
      </tr>
      <% if !@order.order_items.any? %>
        <% @order.order_items.each do |order_item| %>
          <%= render 'hall_tables/partials/product_line', :locals => { :order_item => order_item, :id => id }%>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is jquery code
create.js

```
$('.products-table tr:last').after('<%= render "hall_tables/partials/product_line", :locals => { :item => @item }%>');
```

controller

```
def create
  @order = Order.find(session[:order_id])
  @item = @order.order_items.new(item_params)
  @order.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { }
    format.js { }
  end
end
```

Comment: Please provide more details. Original view, controller and how you call your jquery script

Comment: @AlexanderSysuiev i've edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a javascript error, as it is not escaped. Please check browser console for it.
You can try:

```
$('.products-table tr:last').after('<%= j(render "hall_tables/partials/product_line", :locals => { :item => @item }) %>');
```

Also, make sure that you have `js.erb` extension for create view

Comment: OMG...

That was so obvious. I knew i forgot about something.

Thank you very much !